How a build a source package taken from a previous Ubuntu release?
I'm trying to build curlftpfs sources downloaded from Ubuntu 23.10 universe repository on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS but debuild fails :
$ mkdir -p src/curlftpfs
$ cd src/curlftpfs
$ wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/curlftpfs/curlftpfs_0.9.2-9build1.dsc http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/curlftpfs/curlftpfs_0.9.2.orig.tar.gz http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/curlftpfs/curlftpfs_0.9.2-9build1.debian.tar.xz
--2024-07-22 10:10:01--  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/curlftpfs/curlftpfs_0.9.2-9build1.dsc
Resolving archive.ubuntu.com (archive.ubuntu.com)... 2620:2d:4002:1::103, 2620:2d:4000:1::102, 2620:2d:4002:1::101, ...
Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (archive.ubuntu.com)|2620:2d:4002:1::103|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 2132 (2.1K) [text/prs.lines.tag]
Saving to: ‘curlftpfs_0.9.2-9build1.dsc’

curlftpfs_0.9.2-9build1.dsc     100%[=====================================================>]   2.08K  --.-KB/s    in 0s

2024-07-22 10:10:01 (20.1 MB/s) - ‘curlftpfs_0.9.2-9build1.dsc’ saved [2132/2132]

--2024-07-22 10:10:01--  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/curlftpfs/curlftpfs_0.9.2.orig.tar.gz
Reusing existing connection to [archive.ubuntu.com]:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 365503 (357K) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘curlftpfs_0.9.2.orig.tar.gz’

curlftpfs_0.9.2.orig.tar.gz     100%[=====================================================>] 356.94K   961KB/s    in 0.4s

2024-07-22 10:10:02 (961 KB/s) - ‘curlftpfs_0.9.2.orig.tar.gz’ saved [365503/365503]

--2024-07-22 10:10:02--  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/curlftpfs/curlftpfs_0.9.2-9build1.debian.tar.xz
Reusing existing connection to [archive.ubuntu.com]:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 5140 (5.0K) [application/x-xz]
Saving to: ‘curlftpfs_0.9.2-9build1.debian.tar.xz’

curlftpfs_0.9.2-9build1.debian. 100%[=====================================================>]   5.02K  --.-KB/s    in 0s

2024-07-22 10:10:02 (26.7 MB/s) - ‘curlftpfs_0.9.2-9build1.debian.tar.xz’ saved [5140/5140]

FINISHED --2024-07-22 10:10:02--
Total wall clock time: 0.7s
Downloaded: 3 files, 364K in 0.4s (979 KB/s)
$ ll
total 372
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin-linux admin-linux   5140 2018-04-03 18:36:31 curlftpfs_0.9.2-9build1.debian.tar.xz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin-linux admin-linux   2132 2018-04-03 18:36:31 curlftpfs_0.9.2-9build1.dsc
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin-linux admin-linux 365503 2008-08-20 12:04:55 curlftpfs_0.9.2.orig.tar.gz
$ debuilt
Command 'debuilt' not found, did you mean:
  command 'debuild' from deb devscripts (2.23.7)
Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
$ sudo apt install devscripts -V
...
$ tar -xf curlftpfs_0.9.2-9build1.debian.tar.xz
$ tar -xf curlftpfs_0.9.2.orig.tar.gz
$ ll
total 380
drwxrwxr-x 5 admin-linux admin-linux   4096 2008-05-28 02:52:54 curlftpfs-0.9.2/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin-linux admin-linux   5140 2018-04-03 18:36:31 curlftpfs_0.9.2-9build1.debian.tar.xz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin-linux admin-linux   2132 2018-04-03 18:36:31 curlftpfs_0.9.2-9build1.dsc
-rw-rw-r-- 1 admin-linux admin-linux 365503 2008-08-20 12:04:55 curlftpfs_0.9.2.orig.tar.gz
drwxrwxr-x 4 admin-linux admin-linux   4096 2018-04-03 14:18:10 debian/
$ debuild
This package has a Debian revision number but there does not seem to be
an appropriate original tar file or .orig directory in the parent directory;
(expected one of curlftpfs_0.9.2.orig.tar.gz, curlftpfs_0.9.2.orig.tar.bz2,
curlftpfs_0.9.2.orig.tar.lzma,  curlftpfs_0.9.2.orig.tar.xz or curlftpfs.orig)
continue anyway? (y/n) y
 dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -ui
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source package curlftpfs
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source version 0.9.2-9build1
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source distribution bionic
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source changed by Balint Reczey <rbalint@ubuntu.com>
 dpkg-source --before-build .
dpkg-buildpackage: info: host architecture amd64
dpkg-checkbuilddeps: error: Unmet build dependencies: cdbs (>= 0.4.23-1.1) debhelper (>= 5) libglib2.0-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libfuse-dev dh-autoreconf
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: build dependencies/conflicts unsatisfied; aborting
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: (Use -d flag to override.)
debuild: fatal error at line 1184:
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -ui failed
$ sudo apt install -V cdbs debhelper libglib2.0-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libfuse-dev dh-autoreconf
...
$ debuild
This package has a Debian revision number but there does not seem to be
an appropriate original tar file or .orig directory in the parent directory;
(expected one of curlftpfs_0.9.2.orig.tar.gz, curlftpfs_0.9.2.orig.tar.bz2,
curlftpfs_0.9.2.orig.tar.lzma,  curlftpfs_0.9.2.orig.tar.xz or curlftpfs.orig)
continue anyway? (y/n) y
 dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -ui
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source package curlftpfs
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source version 0.9.2-9build1
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source distribution bionic
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source changed by Balint Reczey <rbalint@ubuntu.com>
 dpkg-source --before-build .
dpkg-buildpackage: info: host architecture amd64
 fakeroot debian/rules clean
CDBS: parsing curlftpfs_0.9.2.orig.tar.gz ...
Parsing curlftpfs_0.9.2.orig.tar.gz...
test -x debian/rules
rm -f debian/stamp-makefile-build debian/stamp-makefile-install
/usr/bin/make -C . -k distclean
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/admin-linux/src/curlftpfs'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'distclean'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/admin-linux/src/curlftpfs'
make: [/usr/share/cdbs/1/class/makefile.mk:91: makefile-clean] Error 2 (ignored)
rm -f debian/stamp-autotools
rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty .
rmdir: failed to remove '.': Invalid argument
make: [/usr/share/cdbs/1/class/autotools.mk:64: makefile-clean] Error 1 (ignored)
set -e;
if test -e debian/autoreconf.before; then \
        dh_autoreconf_clean ; \
fi
dh_clean
dh_clean: error: Compatibility levels before 7 are no longer supported (level 5 requested)
make: *** [/usr/share/cdbs/1/rules/debhelper.mk:213: clean] Error 25
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules clean subprocess returned exit status 2
debuild: fatal error at line 1184:
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -ui failed
$ echo $?
29
$

Can you help me ?

Use a Docker/LXC container of Ubuntu 23.10 and build it? Or maybe use pbuilder to have it create a chroot of 23.10 and build it?
